# setOrientation deprecated in ios6

Tags: xcode, deprecated

I've been doing this way for 2 years:

```
 [[self previewLayer] setOrientation:cameraOrientation];
```

I am finally updating my project for ios6 only to find that "setOrientation" is deprecated. Normally, there is great documentation on this, but I can't find it anywhere. Answers or links welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to keep compatibility with older versions. (Dont forget to change my "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]" to whatever orientation you want to set)

```
if ([self.previewLayer respondsToSelector:@selector(connection)])
    {
        if ([self.previewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported])
        {
            [self.previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Deprecated in 6.0; here for backward compatibility
        if ([self.previewLayer isOrientationSupported])
        {
            [self.previewLayer setOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
        }                
    }
```